# create n item long playlist-like list from multiple other lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to create a list with values out of three other lists (high, medium and low). The new list should evaluate from the probability_array from which list it should pick a random value. The new list should be playlist-like: before a randomly chosen value will be picked twice (from high, medium or low), all other values of the specific list (high, medium or low) must be in the newly generated list.

Any ideas, how I can achieve this. My code so far:

```
import numpy as np


array_length = 30

high = [(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9)]
medium = [10, 11, (12, 13), 14]
low = [100, 101, 102, (103, 104)]

probability_array = np.random.choice(
    ['High', 'Medium', 'Low',],
    array_length,
    p=[4/7, 2/7, 1/7]
)
# i. e.
"""
['Low' 'High' 'High' 'High' 'High' 'High' 'Medium' 'Medium' 'High' 'Medium'
 'High' 'High' 'Medium' 'Medium' 'High' 'High' 'Medium' 'Medium' 'High'
 'High' 'High' 'High' 'High' 'Medium' 'Medium' 'High' 'High' 'High' 'Low'
 'High']
"""

# new list should look like:
"""
[102, (1, 2), 4, (7, 8, 9), 3, 6, 14, ...]
"""
```

Thanks

Comment: My initial comment was misguided. Interesting question. My first attempt would be to massively extend each list by itself with intermittent shuffling. So create `new_high = []`, shuffle `high`, `extend` the `new_high` list by the shuffled `high`, shuffle `high` again, and then extend `new_high` again etc.. Then you just consume your 3 extended lists in the order determined by `probability_array`. This is quite a crude approach but it would work; interested to see what others come up with :)

Comment: Although I don't think any reasonable approach could ensure that the same song from a single list wasn't played back-to-back without violating your distribution. At any arbitrary section of your extended sequence you could easily end up violating your criteria multiple times but the sequence as a whole would be valid

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. To be more clear: the same song i.e. from the list "high" could be placed twice or more in the final list, as long as any other song from the "high" list is already used once, twice, etc. You can think of a randomly playlist in a randomly playlist.

Comment: Then my approach would definitely work. For the first iteration (i.e. tracks are being repeated for the first time) then it _guarantees_ that all tracks have been played at least once before being played again from any list. I'm assuming that this isn't an actual music playlist though, so I don't know if you have some deeper criteria because repeated items in the sequence (back-to-back) are also, if the sequence is long enough, pretty much guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `np.random.choice` there is an option to specify the probability of items being chosen. You can build a list of `high, medium, low` with that and feed it into another loop to construct your playlist correctly
- at roganjosh's suggestion, I also removed the ability for the same item to occur back to back

```
import numpy as np
import random 
import collections 

playlist_length = 30

# key is the match strength (ie. high, medium, low)
matches = {
    'high' : {
        'items' : [(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9)],
        'prob' : 4/7
    },
    'medium' : {
        'items' : [10, 11, (12, 13), 14],
        'prob' : 2/7
    },
    'low' : {
        'items' : [100, 101, 102, (103, 104)],
        'prob' : 1/7
    }
}

# create two lists:
# a is a list of match strengths 
# p is the desired probability of an item from that match strength occuring
a, p = zip(*[(match, matches[match]['prob']) for match in matches])

# build a list of match strengths, with our chosen size and probability
results = np.random.choice(a=a, p=p, size=playlist_length)

# build our playlist 
playlist = []
last_item = None
for match_strength in results:
    # count all the items currently in playlist (a bit inefficient, probably don't have to recreate the Counter obj everytime)
    count_playlist = collections.Counter(playlist)

    # filter items of the given match strength, leaving out those that are at the current max 
    items = matches[match_strength]['items']
    max_count = max([count_playlist[item] for item in items])
    filtered = list(filter(lambda item: count_playlist[item] < max_count, items))

    # if all items have the same count, reset the filtered list to be any item
    if not len(filtered):
        filtered = items

    # drop last item so that it does not repeat
    if last_item and last_item in filtered and len(filtered) > 1:
        filtered.remove(last_item)

    # add one from filtered items to playlist
    new_item = random.choice(filtered)
    playlist.append(new_item)
    last_item = new_item

print(collections.Counter(results))
print(playlist)
```

#### output:

the counter shows that the different match strength occur at acceptable frequencies `Counter({'high': 19, 'medium': 10, 'low': 1})`

and the playlist was
`[(1, 2), 14, 4, 5, 102, 3, (7, 8, 9), 6, (1, 2), 11, 10, (12, 13), 4, 3, 10, (12, 13), 5, 11, (7, 8, 9), 14, 6, 4, (7, 8, 9), 5, 10, (1, 2), 6, 3, 11, 4]`

Comment: Interesting approach. I can't test right now but iiuc every entry from each list is fair game, then you block out those that have already appeared a disproportionate amount of times, and select randomly from the remainder?

Comment: yep. This means that no song should be played more than once over any other song of it's category

Comment: At a glance it achieves the same as mine and has same pitfall for back-to-back duplicate entries, but certainly a contrast in approaches, which is beneficial. I don't think there is a truly clean way :)

Comment: oh? i think i misunderstood, i thought no item was supposed to play twice before other items of that category were played. I can update it to solve that too

Comment: You didn't misunderstand, OP never specified, but it's a clear issue in my mind

Comment: I haven't looked at your method yet, but it's quite an easy way to solve with this one -in fact, I just included it

Comment: At any arbitrary subset of the final sequence the criteria can be horribly broken. I eluded in comments that this could be an issue because I don't think this is a music playlist but it was not addressed.

Comment: I guess I read too much into it, the question is answered twice in two different and valid ways. I like your approach.

Comment: Thanks for this clear solution. I'll test today all answers back-and-forth.

Answer (score 0):

I make no claims to the efficiency of this approach (it illustrates one potential method rather than final code) but it will work by ensuring that each list (`high`, `medium`, `low`) is consumed entirely before it gets repeated for a second time etc. It will work for a final sequence of any length but it can easily result in the same "track" appearing back-to-back. It was not clarified in comments whether this was an issue.

```
import numpy as np

array_length = 30

high = [(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9)]
medium = [10, 11, (12, 13), 14]
low = [100, 101, 102, (103, 104)]

# Initialise exntended lists
new_high = []
new_medium = []
new_low = []

# Create extended lists as repeating units

for x in range(3):
    np.random.shuffle(high)
    np.random.shuffle(medium)
    np.random.shuffle(low)
    new_high.extend(high)
    new_medium.extend(medium)
    new_low.extend(low)

# Probability distribution for consuming the extended lists
probability_array = np.random.choice(
    ['High', 'Medium', 'Low',],
    array_length,
    p=[4.0/7, 2.0/7, 1.0/7]
)

# Our final sequence
playlist = []

# Keep track of how far we got through each of the extended lists
high_counter, medium_counter, low_counter = 0, 0, 0

for pick in probability_array:
    if pick == 'High':
        playlist.append(new_high[high_counter])
        high_counter += 1
    elif pick == 'Medium':
        playlist.append(new_medium[medium_counter])
        medium_counter += 1
    else:
        playlist.append(new_low[low_counter])
        low_counter += 1

print(playlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def make_list(high, medium, low, parr):        
    _, (nhigh, nlow, nmed) = np.unique(parr, return_counts=True)
    # A check can be added to make sure labels are in the set ['High', 'Low', 'Medium']
    dl = {}
    dl['High'] = (nhigh // len(high) + 1) * np.random.permutation(np.asanyarray(high, dtype=np.object)).tolist()
    dl['Medium'] = (nmed // len(medium) + 1) * np.random.permutation(np.asanyarray(medium, dtype=np.object)).tolist()
    dl['Low'] = (nlow // len(low) + 1) * np.random.permutation(np.asanyarray(low, dtype=np.object)).tolist()
    play_list = []
    for p in parr:
        play_list.append(dl[p].pop())
    return play_list
```